# Haddock hyperlinks and without warning about redundant imports

Tags: haskell, haddock

I have a dummy module in my project, whose sole purpose is to hold Haddock documentation for the rest of the library. In fact I don't *need* to import anything in this module, but if I don't import other modules, Haddock doesn't hyperlink function names to their modules.

My module looks like this

```
{- |

Lots of Haddock text here... it references 'someFunction'.

-}
module TopLevelDoc () where

import Other.Module.With.SomeFunction
```

Now if I build the project, I get this warning:

```
    Warning: The import of `Other.Module.With.SomeFunction' is redundant
           except perhaps to import instances from `Other.Module.With.SomeFunction'
         To import instances alone, use: import Other.Module.With.SomeFunction()
```

If I remove imports or make them `()`, Haddock doesn't hyperlink `someFunction` to its documentation. If I leave such imports as is, I get lots of false warnings, which I don't like. And I don't want to suppress this kind of warning for the entire project, it may be useful for any other module but this one.

Questions:

1. How do I get hyperlinked Haddock output without such warnings when building?
2. Is it possible to disable warnings on per-file basis? (like I can do it globally with `ghc-options` in `.cabal`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To silence the unused import warning, you can put a pragma at the top of your file:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-imports #-}
```

You can link to to identifiers that aren't in scope by explicitly qualifying them:

> It is also possible to refer to entities that are not in scope in the current module, by giving the full qualified name of the entity:
>
> ```
> -- | The identifier 'M.T' is not in scope
> ```
>
> If M.T is not otherwise in scope, then Haddock will simply emit a link pointing to the entity T exported from module M (without checking to see whether either M or M.T exist).
>
> — [The Haddock User Guide](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html#id566119)

However, this will probably make your documentation source quite ugly, and the module qualifications aren't removed from the output, so I'd recommend turning off the warnings instead.

Comment: Thank you. `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-imports #-}` works just fine. Both questions answered.